# A Map is continuous on the inverse image of the set $(-\infty,r]$. Does this inverse image a closed set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Let $U$ be a topological space and a map $g:U\to \mathbb{R}$. For a given $r\in\mathbb{R}$, define $E:= \{x\in U: g(x)\leq r\}$. If $g$ is continuous at every point of $E$, then Is it true that $E$ is closed set in U? If yes, prove it. If not, give counter example.

My guess is yes.. Here is my attempt. Let $x_n\in E$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = x$. I am trying to prove $x\in E$. By continuity of $g$, we have $g(x_n)$ also converges. Moreover, $g(x_n)\leq r$ for all $n$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)\leq r$.

Here I am stuck. If I prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)=g(x)$, I am done. Can somebody help me here.

Comment: At which point of $U$ are you using the continuity of $g$? Are you confident that $g$ is continuous there?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? Have you try to apply it to the sequence $\{g_n(x)\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. E.g. $U=\Bbb R$ and $E=(0,\infty).$ Let $r=1.$ Let $g(x)=0$ for $x\in E.$ Let $g(x)=2$ for $x\le 0.$

If you also want $g$ to be discontinuous at every point of $U$ \ $E$ then modify the example above to $g(x)=2$ when $0\ge x\in \Bbb Q$ and $g(x)=3$ when $0>x\not\in \Bbb Q.$

Given a non-empty space $E$ we can always find a space $U$ such that $E$ is an open, non-closed subspace of $U.$ For example let $U=E\cup \{p\}$ with $p\not\in E.$ Let $T_E$ be the topology on $E$ and let the topology on $U$ be $\{U\}\cup T_E.$

If $E$ is an open, non-closed subspace of $U,$ let $r=1.$ Let $g(x)=0$ for $x\in E.$ Let $g(x)=2$ for $x\in U$ \ $E.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $U=\Bbb R$ and $r=0$, and define $f$ as follows:

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\tan x,&\text{if }-\frac{\pi}2<x<\frac{\pi}2\\
1,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Then $E=\left(-\frac{\pi}2,0\right]$, $f$ is continuous on $E$ (and indeed everywhere except $\pm\frac{\pi}2$), and $E$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$.